# if versus if/else with regard to boolean

Tags: c++

Which of the following two implementation is best and why?

```
bool MyClass::hasCContainerValues(CContainer* container)
{
    if(container && container->nrOfValues>0) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool MyClass::hasCContainerValues(CContainer* container)
{
    if(container && container->nrOfValues>0) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return (container && container->nrOfValues>0);`

Comment: @zch: +1 because that was my first thought too :-)

Comment: what zch said and /thread.

Comment: These is no difference. Just how you write.

Comment: What I want to recommend is: read 'Code Complete II' :)

Comment: If you're paid by the line, the the second is obviously better. Otherwise, what @zch said: there's no reason to use flow control to convert a boolean expression into exactly the same boolean value.

Answer (score 4):

Making the assumption that you aren't doing anything more than just the simple test, go with:

```
bool MyClass::hasCContainerValues(CContainer* container) const
{
    return (container && container->nrOfValues>0);
}
```

However, if you were to do more, then it is sometimes thought that a single exit point is better (various static analysis rulesets complain about multiple exit points, [rightly](http://www.codingstandard.com/HICPPCM/High_Integrity_CPP_Rule_5.9.html) or [wrongly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18454)):

```
bool MyClass::hasCContainerValues(CContainer* container) const
{
    bool retval = false;
    if(container && container->nrOfValues>0) 
    {
        // something else here perhaps
        retval = true;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Also, as an aside, if you're only testing the content, then you could probably make the method `const`, but that's irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I would [beg to differ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/18454/7043) regarding neatness.

Comment: OK, perhaps neatness is the wrong wording. The reason I was referred to having a single exit point is as I've been doing a lot of static analysis recently, and the rules we're using don't like multiple exits... I must have done something wrong in a previous life. I'll remove the neatness comment :)

Comment: That's a refreshingly realistic reason for preferring single exit points, cheers for that! And boo for the static analysis tool author who fails at flow analysis.

Comment: I've updated my answer to mention that, and blatantly stolen your link. For reference, things like High Integrity C++ rule 5.9 state single entry/exit with the exception of... exceptions. I've yet to find a static analysis ruleset that actually makes code more readable.

Comment: Regarding `const`, it would make more sense to make it `static` (or a non-member) if it isn't already, since it doesn't access `this` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that it is an example and you don't want to do just `return (container && container->nrOfValues>0)`, they are both OK and equally correct.

The rest is personal opinion/taste and it will create a religious war here.
I personally prefer the first, but might choose either depending on complexity of both clauses i.e. logic in `true` and `false` path.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter ... If you use a modern compiler, it will optimize and transform your code. 
Your 2 snippets can produce exactly the same code.

Comment: -1 That doesn't mean it doesn't matter. That only means it doesn't matter for performance, but it didn't matter for performance to begin with. Leaving out indentation or prefixing all variable names with `var` doesn't affect performance either, but I doubt anyone considers doing that as good as not doing it.

Comment: @delnan lol you see a difference between the 2 snippets ? >< Did the OP ask for best practices, conventions etc ? NO ...

Comment: I indeed see a difference, especially if we consider the code just an example standing for more complex bodies. And OP asked "which [...] is best and why" -- that's literally the whole question. No mention of performance either.

Comment: Considere what you want, the OP doesn't :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, the shorter form of code doesn't hurt the code readibility so it is better to use the shorter form which is, the first one. Because is is readable and in has less lines of code.